# How can i select first record of each distinct couple of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table where i can have records like this:

| ID | ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 | 10 |
| 3 | 12 | 10 |
| 4 | 10 | 12 |

I need to select first record of each distinct couple of ColA and ColB.

Expected result:

| ID | ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 12 | 10 |

I dont't need the ID column, just the single couple of ColA and ColB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` here along with least/greatest logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                     CASE WHEN ColA <= ColB THEN ColA ELSE ColB END,
                                     CASE WHEN ColA > ColB  THEN ColA ELSE ColB END
                                 ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, ColA, ColB
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Explanation:

The two `CASE` expressions which appear in the partition clause of `ROW_NUMBER` find the smallest and greatest of the two columns `ColA` and `ColB`, for each record.  So, we partition on the pair of least/greatest of the two columns, and then retain the record for each pair having the smallest `ID` value.